# From Sublime Text to Webstorm

Tags: sublimetext, webstorm

I'm starting to use JetBRAINS webstorm. I have a few keyboard shortcuts I frequently use in Sublime text. I would like to know what the equivalent is in webstorm.

1. in Sublime I could select a line of code with `Ctrl+L`. If you press `Ctrl+L` again it would select an additional line. This was handy for quickly selecting entire methods etc.
2. In sublime you can have multiple carets allowing you to create mass amounts of code. Does webstorm have anything like this (built in or plugin).

   **EDIT:** Now in webstorm 8 you can do this by Center Clicking your mouse and dragging down the code. Neat.
3. in sublime you could re-indent selected parts of code: `Edit > Line > Re-indent`.

I think that's all for now.

Sorry for the n00b questions I just wanna get back to coding quickly and efficiently with my new toy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1)** <kbd>Ctrl + W</kbd> (`Edit | Select Word at Caret`) few times in a row.

**2)** Available in PhpStorm v8/WebStorm v8/IntelliJ IDEA v13.1 (not sure about PyCharm and RubyMine versions -- must be build 136.1153 or newer)

More details [in blog post here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/03/working-with-multiple-selection-in-phpstorm-8-eap/).

**3)** `Code | Auto-Indent Lines` *I guess* (sorry, I do not know what original one in ST does exactly -- never used ST myself).

---

> Sorry for the n00b questions I just wanna get back to coding quickly and efficiently with my new toy.

a) `Help | Default Keymap Reference` for quick overview.

b) `Help | Find Action...` (<kbd>Ctrl + Shift + A</kbd>) is very handy tool for new (and not only) users / does miracles.

Answer (score 2):

On a Mac (I'm on OS X Mountain Lion, Webstorm 8), you could

1) hit Alt + Up Arrow. Doing so repeatedly selects the next bigger block of text, right up to a function and eventually the whole file.

2) do what the guy said above

3) select your text and select Code->Reformat Code (or hit Cmd + Alt + L)

HTH.